# can not connect google cloud instance using node.js

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, database-connection, google-cloud-sql

i am new to node js.
i created a sql instance on google cloud
and i need connect to mysql db.
i am using public ip
i want try this [sample](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine-standard#connect_to) code what is it socketPath?
how can i find it?
i created [app.standard.yaml](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/blob/3259904684ebaf199faef4a6e3518c911b80cc2b/cloud-sql/mysql/mysql/app.standard.yaml) file and filled it parameters with the necessary information
but my code not working in  cloud shell editor

```
var con= mysql.createPool({
  socketPath : '/cloudsql/[INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME]',
  user: db_user, // e.g. 'my-db-user'
  password: db_password, // e.g. 'my-db-password'
  database: db_name' // e.g. 'my-database'
});
```

i found INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME value in instance overview section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Behind the scenes App Engine uses the [Cloud SQL Auth Proxy](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudsql-proxy) to connect to a Cloud SQL instance.

If you want to run the sample code in Cloud Shell, you'll need to start the proxy the same way App Engine does in the shell like so, where `INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME` is `YOUR_PROJECT_ID:YOUR_DB_REGION:YOUR_CLOUD_SQL_INSTANCE_NAME`.

```
sudo mkdir /cloudsql
sudo chown `whoami` /cloudsql
cloud_sql_proxy -instances=INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME -dir /cloudsql
```

Then in a new tab, you can run the sample code.

Comment: Gives an error message: Rlimits for file descriptors set to {Current = 8500, Max = 1048576}

Comment: That's a totally normal log message. Does the proxy say anything after that?

Comment: yes " listen unix /cloudsql/INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME : bind: permission denied"

Comment: I missed a step above about updating the permissions of the directory. I've edited my answer and tested that a fresh cloudshell works with just the three steps above.